# Duda sobre IF SQL y comprobar si un select devuelve registros

Tags: sql, sql-server

En una tabla llamada `pacientes` tengo a `Juan`, que es `varchar (4)`.

Mi `if` tiene el siguiente inconveniente `Juan` puede ser `Pedro` o `José`. O sea, puede variar este nombre infinidad de veces yo necesito un `IF` que entre en `Begin` si `Select` muestra resultado.

El siguiente `IF` muestra creo solo alfa-numérico en `>0`

Quiero que si `select` muestra 'X' de resultado entre en `Begin`, lo que tenía estará algo como este

```
IF (SELECT Nombre FROM Tabla WHERE CEDULA)>0
BEGIN
PRINT 'Entro'
END 
ELSE
PRNT 'NO ENTRO'
```

Entiéndase que para mi creo que `>0` "Mayor que 0" ¿quiere decir Muestra cantidad de Rows Mostrados o me equivoco? ¿o muestra si el número de `select` es mayor entonces entra?

¿Cómo se escribiría de manera correcta?

Hice este #Temp (Tabla Temporal) a ver que tal pero no me dio resultado.

```
CREATE TAble #Temp 
(
NOMBRE varchar (250)
)

INSERT #Temp Values ('Juan');

IF (SELECT Nombre FROM #temp)>0
BEGIN
PRINT 'EXITO'
END
ELSE
PRINT 'NO EXISTE'
```

Muy importante la palabra `juan` son combinaciones de la A-Z osea miles de combinaciones

osea quiero una solucion a la linea

```
IF (SELECT Nombre FROM #temp)>0
```

esta la tome como varchar y no como int

Comment: He leído dos veces tu pregunta y la verdad no logro comprender ni tu problema ni lo que quieres conseguir. Creo que comienzas hablando de un problema específico, pero luego, en lugar de mostrar el código real y datos reales, hablas de supuestos y pegas código que de cualquier forma no correría en SQL (por errores de sintaxis), con eso, me quedo mareado y ya no se que es lo que realmente haces y menos logro entender el problema que tienes o lo que quieres conseguir.

Comment: hey Juan, te parece si le agregas la estructura de tus tablas tal cual son, con alguna data de ejemplo para entender, porque así como @jachguate ha leído 2 veces tu pregunta, me encuentro en la misma situación: no está claro lo que preguntas, te invito a editarla para que se entienda mejor :D saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para saber el número de filas devueltas por un select , usarías la función [count(*)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-pe/library/ms175997.aspx)

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) from #temp)<>0 --Hay resultados
BEGIN
PRINT 'EXITO'
END
ELSE
PRINT 'NO EXISTE'
```